# Panning JS canvas

Tags: javascript, animation, canvas

I'm experimenting in canvas and trying to create pan effect. I've managed to pan succesfully, but I'm curious if I'm doing it correctly. Since I've come up with the following code myself, I don't know if there is a better way to accomplish the task.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/0Lh671kp/)

```js
var canvas    = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context   = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = 600;
canvas.height = 400;

var global = {
 scale : 1,
 offset : {
  x : 0,
  y : 0,
 },
};
var pan = {
 start : {
  x : null,
  y : null,
 },
 offset : {
  x : 0,
  y : 0,
 },
};

function draw() {
 context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 
 context.translate(pan.offset.x, pan.offset.y);
 
 context.beginPath();
 context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
 context.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
 context.fill();
 
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(350, 250, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = 'green';
 context.fill();
}

draw();

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPan);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseleave", endPan);
canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", endPan);

function startPan(e) {
 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", trackMouse);
 canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", draw);
 pan.start.x = e.clientX;
 pan.start.y = e.clientY;
}

function endPan(e) {
 canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", trackMouse);
 canvas.removeEventListener("mousemove", draw);
 pan.start.x = null;
 pan.start.y = null;
 global.offset.x = pan.offset.x;
 global.offset.y = pan.offset.y;
}

function trackMouse(e) {
 var offsetX  = e.clientX - pan.start.x;
 var offsetY  = e.clientY - pan.start.y;
 pan.offset.x = global.offset.x + offsetX;
 pan.offset.y = global.offset.y + offsetY;
}
```

```css
body {
 background: gainsboro;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

Updated version of the pan (using the tips Flambino provided):

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/akinuri/0Lh671kp/1/)

```js
var canvas    = document.getElementById("canvas");
var context   = canvas.getContext("2d");
canvas.width  = 600;
canvas.height = 400;

var global = {
 scale : 1,
 offset : {
  x : 0,
  y : 0,
 },
};
var panning = {
 start : {
  x : null,
  y : null,
 },
 offset : {
  x : 0,
  y : 0,
 },
};

function draw() {
 context.beginPath();
 context.rect(50, 50, 100, 100);
 context.fillStyle = 'skyblue';
 context.fill();
 
 context.beginPath();
 context.arc(350, 250, 50, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
 context.fillStyle = 'green';
 context.fill();
}

draw();

canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", startPan);

function pan() {
 context.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
 context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
 context.translate(panning.offset.x, panning.offset.y);
 draw();
}

function startPan(e) {
 window.addEventListener("mousemove", trackMouse);
 window.addEventListener("mousemove", pan);
 window.addEventListener("mouseup", endPan);
 panning.start.x = e.clientX;
 panning.start.y = e.clientY;
}

function endPan(e) {
 window.removeEventListener("mousemove", trackMouse);
 window.removeEventListener("mousemove", pan);
 window.removeEventListener("mouseup", endPan);
 panning.start.x = null;
 panning.start.y = null;
 global.offset.x = panning.offset.x;
 global.offset.y = panning.offset.y;
}

function trackMouse(e) {
 var offsetX  = e.clientX - panning.start.x;
 var offsetY  = e.clientY - panning.start.y;
 panning.offset.x = global.offset.x + offsetX;
 panning.offset.y = global.offset.y + offsetY;
}
```

```css
body {
 background: gainsboro;
 margin: 0;
}
canvas {
 background: white;
 box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems fine to me!

The only things I would be add would be to set up the `endPan` event handlers in `mousedown` (and remove them in `endPan`) the same way you do with `mousemove`.

I'd also separate the draw function from the translate function. Those two tasks are separate: One handles the panning, regardless of what's to be drawn, and the other draws, regardless of the panning. So having that in one function is lumping too many things into one.

You could instead have a `pan` function that sets the translation, and then calls `draw()`. That'll keep things apart.

From a UX standpoint, I'd add the mousemove and mouseup listeners to `window`, and skip the `mouseleave` listener. It's jarring when the panning stops just because you moved outside the canvas. It feels more natural for the panning to just keep following your mouse as long as hold the button down.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Implemented them right away! Now, off to creating zoom effect  :)